# Get current Route object from inside $app->before filter?

Tags: symfony, silex

Using [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/), how can I get the current Route object from inside a `before` filter? e.g.,

```
$app->before(function() use ($app) {
    // need to access Route for matched URL here
});
```

I need the whole object, not just the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not tested, but this should work.

```php
$app->before(function(Request $req, Application $app) {
    $route = $app['routes']->get($req->get('_route'));
});
```

Just curious, why you need the Route object?

Comment: That looks like it works, awesome! There's no way to do it without accessing the internal `_route`? I've extended the Route object and I want to put some authorization info it, so I can do `$app->get('/secret/page', function(){ ... })->restrict('ADMIN')`. Going to kick them back to the login page from inside the `before` filter if they don't match.

Comment: Got it! Regarding `_route`, no other way that I'm aware of.